# Return a ResultSet from EntityManager

Tags: jpa, resultset

I am updating an application.  I have replaced most of the queries in the app with calls to ejbs but the code below calls a huge procedure and it would be almost impossible to re-write.

I would like to return an ejb to the result set R but I have not been able to figure this out....

```
  java.sql.ResultSet R = Cmd.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TableData");
   String[] Names = {"id","Project","Resource","Week","Hours"};
   out.print(getTableXML(R,Names));
   R.close();
```

My ejb:

```
public List<Gridmaster> getDisplayGridList() {
            return em.createQuery("FROM Gridmaster order by gridid", Gridmaster.class).getResultList();
```

Is this possible or do I need to create an old style db connection?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why don't you change the `getTableXML` to take `List<Gridmaster>` as argument instead?

Comment: Wish it was so easy.  It does not take it as an argument (don't ask...).  The app uses a 3rd party software call ejs Tree Grid.  In the getTableXML the result set is reference hundreds of times and it would be too big of a deal to re-program it plus it might break the 3rd party software opening up a Pandora's box.

Comment: 1. JPQL has to begin with SELECT. 2. I know of no provider that will expose the ResultSet since that is the responsibility of the JPA provider to handle. The closest you will likely get will be the java.sql.Connection and that depends on which provider ... which you don't mention